# Loan Calculator Using jQuery Slider Passing Inaccurate Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a loan calculator that is using the jQuery UI slider element. As the slider moves I am displaying that value in a label to the user. However, I'm also using that value to calculate other values such as monthly repayment etc.

I can't seem to figure out why the value being displayed to the user in the label is correct (IE when the slider is all the way to the left, it displays 5000 and when it's all the way to the right it displays 500000), but the value being passed into the loan calculations is always 5000 off.

```
# JS
function computeLoan() {
  var amount = $('#slider1').slider('value');
  var months = parseInt(document.getElementById('months').value);
  var completionFee = 0;
  var interest_rate = 0.06;
  var monthly_interest_rate = interest_rate / 12;
  var payment = amount * (monthly_interest_rate * (Math.pow(1 + monthly_interest_rate, months))) / (Math.pow(1 + monthly_interest_rate, months) -1);
  monthly_payment = payment.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById('afterCompletion').innerHTML = "$"+amountMinusCompletion.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  document.getElementById('payment').innerHTML = "$"+monthly_payment.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  payable = parseInt(monthly_payment * months).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById('payable').innerHTML = "$"+payable.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
$('#slider1').slider({
  min: 5000,
  max: 500000,
  step: 5000,
  slide: function(event, ui)
    {
      $('#slider1-value').text("$"+ui.value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
      computeLoan();
    }
});

# HTML
<select class="form-control" id="months" onchange="computeLoan()">
    <option value="6" selected>6 Months</option>
    <option value="12">12 Months</option>
    <option value="18">18 Months</option>
    <option value="24">24 Months</option>
    <option value="36">36 Months</option>
    <option value="48">48 Months</option>
    <option value="60">60 Months</option>
</select>

<label for="" class="col-md-6 control-label color-purple" id="slider1-value"></label>
```

When I change the value on the form using the select field, the correct value is pulled from the slider and used in the calculations, however when sliding the slider without changing the term in the select field, it is off by 5000 until I then change the term.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I will say that the assignment `amount = $('#slider1').slider('value');` above the call to `computeLoan` looks suspicious.  That assignment does not have the `amount` variable from the `computeLoan` function in scope, so it is setting to a global variable called `amount`, which might not be what was intended.  I'm not sure if that is the source of the problem, though.

Comment: @jpolitz thanks for pointing that out. I removed it, it wasn't the source of the problem but its nice to clean up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Slide` event occurs when slider changes, so you're validating value before you stop. I suppose there's a very very slight delay that causes the value not to be passed on your compute loan function. You have a couple of solution, maybe the cleanest would be to add a `stop` event to make sure you get the value when you stop. But you could set a timeout also. 
Example with the stop event:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slider1').slider({
    min: 5000,
    max: 500000,
    step: 5000,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $('#slider1-value').text("$" + ui.value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
      computeValue()

    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $('#slider1-value').text("$" + ui.value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
      computeValue();

    }
  });

  function computeValue() {
    var amount = $('#slider1').slider('value');
    $('#slider1-computedvalue').text(amount.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id='slider1'></div>
<div id='slider1-value'></div>
<div id='slider1-computedvalue'></div>
```

Comment: I'm still trying to get this solution to work in my app. I'll post back with results shortly.